# Add a simple image tag to the DOM instead of using a GWT Widget to have better JS runtime performance

Tags: javascript, image, performance, gwt

I'am dealing with a resource constraint embedded browser.
What is the best way (JS runtime performance) to add a simple image (no handlers needed) to an HTML document at runtime?
It seems to me that Widgets come with some overhead, so is it better to add the HTML tag to the DOM directly?

thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study about  [GWT-UI Binder](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html)

> The UiBinder framework allows you to do exactly that: build your apps as HTML pages with GWT widgets sprinkled throughout them.